# How to play without "loading" screen in CAF custom player. (HLS with QueueData)

Tags: javascript, chromecast, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I want seamless playback multiple video contents. (HLS/using queueData)

preloading is works! but when the video changes, "loading" screen is displayed.

How i can playback without "loading" screen in CAF custom player?

Answer (score 1):

Even though a `PRELOAD` request starts buffering the next item of your queue to reduce the loading time for the next clip, playback is never 'seamless'.

Every time the actual `LOAD` request comes in, the player will (by default) switch to the `BUFFERING` state and display the associated UI until it's back to `PLAYING`

[Google's UX guidelines for autoplay](https://developers.google.com/cast/downloads/GoogleCastAutoplayUXGuidelines.pdf) are quite clear how the UI should behave on the playback of queues - and you might want to consider adhering to that if you want to publish your app. That being said:

Take a look at your HTML - are you using the `<cast-media-player></cast-media-player>` custom tags? You can use CSS to set the appearance of all states of the application - check the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/caf_receiver/customize_ui) for details.

`--buffering-image` and `--spinner-image` are the customizable elements that you can change here. Again: Those will always pop up when the player enters buffering state, so you will have to come up with something less disturbing than the spinner and default image: A black screen, maybe?

Also, you can not simply use CSS to get rid of those: When the playback is initialized and the queue is built, you most likely still want to show them - so totally disabling them is not an option.
The tricky part is finding appropriate [events](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/caf_receiver/cast.framework.events#.EventType) to dis- and re-enable them:

Consider the [MediaFinishedEvent](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/caf_receiver/cast.framework.events#.EventType) to disable them, and maybe the `PLAYER_LOAD_COMPLETE` event to restore them to their default value.
(The [BUFFERING](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/caf_receiver/cast.framework.events.BufferingEvent) event might also work but was very unreliable when I tried to use it.)

Comment: thanks. yes, i tried CSS/image change. but it did not going well. i think about how to do it referring to your comment.